# Does Angular 2+ load whole module or just exported components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a big module but just export 1 component, when I import that module does Angular load the whole module or just the exported components so that I could control the performance? I don't want to move the component to a common module 'cos it breaks the structure. Could anyone give me an advice?

Update code example

Saying I have ModuleA with 3 components and just export 1 of them:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  exports: [
    ComponentA
  ],
  declarations: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
    ComponentC
  ]
})
export class ModuleA { }
```

In ModuleB, I import ModuleA so that I could use ComponentA:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    ModuleA
  ]
})
export class ModuleB { }
```

When the app load ModuleB, does it just load ComponentA or it load all components of ModuleA?

Comment: can you add some code snippet to understand more what is your requirement ?

Comment: Okay I just updated the question. :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It should load all the components mentioned in the module.ts file of ModuleA

Answer (score 0):

So if you are saying:

**module.ts**

```
export const foo;

export const bar;

export const baz;
```

And then 
**component.ts**

```
import { foo } from './module'
```

I *believe* that while in development you will have all members available, when building production builds Angular AoT building will tree-shake the others away. It uses Webpack for doing so.

Webpacks tree shaking mechanisms are explained here:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

And here are the docs to angular AoT compiler:
https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Anyhow, try a prod build and if everything works you should be fine :)

Comment: Sorry my question misled you, I've just updated with the code.